# Subscribe to a stream of events from server

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I am expanding upon ping-pong example of redux-observable, and my final goal is to **dispatch an action upon each received event from server**.

But i am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how to actually achieve this.

What i have so far:

1.Upon opening a connection my server starts sending messages.

```
// server.js
setInterval(()=>{
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: 'INCREMENT',
        status: 200
    }))
    console.log("sent some data")
},3000)
```

2. On the client i have established an Observable of that Websocket connection.

```
const socket$ = Observable.webSocket("ws://localhost:8081")
```

The rest of the code is similar to the [JSBin Example for react](https://jsbin.com/vayoho/14/edit?html,css,js,output)

How do i form an epic for this task? How do i dispatch an action?

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/112

Comment: @eenagy that is rxjs v4 btw and not accurate for v5

Comment: Hey @n3u3w3It it's not clear what you're asking. Could you revise?

Comment: @jayphelps , sure. Basically, i need my app to do the following:



1. Open an app that connects to a server via websocket, app creates an observable of that websocket connection. 
2. Server sends infinite 'INCREMENT' messages to any connected user.
3. Upon receiving each message an action must be dispatched. So if my `state.counter` was zero, upon receiving the event it must become 1,2,3 an so forth

Comment: Have you tried to create an epic, using your Rx knowledge and the docs: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html ? Could you add it to your answer?

Comment: For this example i'd imagine my epic should be something like this

`const incrementEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('NCREMENT_INTENT) // intent to change the state
        .mapTo({type: 'INCREMENT_APPLY'}) // dispatching an action`
The question is - where should i place the "listening to the websocket events" logic ?

Comment: Can you describe how the websocket interacts with this epic? Do you need to send things through the socket? Receive things back? Only listen from the server? Do you need to multiplex or just a single channel?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions :) lots of requirements before I can effectively suggest solutions

Comment: @jayphelps, i simply need to establish a connection when my client app starts and only receive dummy messages from websocket. Server infinitely sends me pings. I have a redux store that looks like `{counter:0}`, and i want to increment that coutner upon each received event. It's single channel, and it's as simple as it may be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discussed a bit in the comments, but I'm afraid I'm still not entirely clear on how the increment/counter/INCREMENT_APPLY relates to the socket, but I can get you a simple example:

```
const somethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('START_SOCKET_OR_WHATEVER')
    .switchMap(action =>
      Observable.webSocket('ws://localhost:8081')
        .map(response => ({ type: 'RECEIVED_MESSAGE', paylod: response }))
    );
```

Here when `START_SOCKET_OR_WHATEVER` is dispatched, we'll start listening to our socket. Whenever a message is received we map it into a `RECEIVED_MESSAGE` action which will be dispatched after when epic emits it.

You'll notice this is nearly identical to how you would do a single ajax too. It only would be become notably different if you need to send messages to the server or multiplex.

Comment: thanks a lot, @jayphelps, this is the exact behavior that i was looking for. I checked it just now and it works as intended - i open a connection by dispatching `SOCKET_START` action, and after action is dispatched my app starts receiving pings from server and increments the counter value

Comment: woohoo! so glad!

Comment: @jayphelps I don't suppose you would be able to additionally point me in the right direction to also listen for socket failure/close events? eg a `{ type: 'SOCKET_CLOSED' }`

Comment: @JoshMc webSocket subject will either complete() or error() subscribers depending on whether it was a clean close. You can also provide a closeObserver as well. If you'd like more specific help, like how to turn that into a redux action you emit, it's probably best to create a new stackoverflow question describing your needs. Hope this helps! https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/259853ebf41dfa1c0bf8f8034c8e6196511f4def/src/internal/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L334-L345

Comment: @jayphelps Thanks for your help, I have given it a go but wasn't able to get very far, will give it another go later tonight, but in the mean time I have created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700859/websocket-epic-that-receives-connection-requests-and-emits-messages-connection