# Redux Observable - How to send off an action to start a separate epic, then wait for that epics response (or timeout)

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

So I basically have a [websocket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700859/websocket-epic-that-receives-connection-message-requests-and-emits-messages), this allows me to send generic messages via WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND and receive them via WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED actions.

However there are cases where I want to make a request in a similar manner to a Ajax REST call. Eg to request a list of documents for a user I probably want to have an epic:

1. Receive an action eg `({ type: GET_DOCUMENTS })`
2. Generate a random key to track the current request, we will call it `'request_id'`
3. Send a `({ type: WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND, request_id })` action.
4. Wait for either of

   1. an action `({ type: WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, request_id, message })` **Must be with a matching 'request_id' otherwise it should be ignored.

      - -> Emit an action eg `({ type: GET_DOCUMENTS_SUCCESS, documents: message })`
   2. a timeout eg 10 seconds

      - -> Emit an action eg `({ type: GET_DOCUMENTS_TIMEOUT })`

I have been struggling to put this into code, I think the most awkward part of the whole epic is that I want to emit an action in the middle of my epic and wait. This doesn't feel quite right to me...  ani-pattern? But I am not really sure how I should be doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. There is no good way to emit an action in the middle of an epic. How about splitting the epic into two?

```js
const getDocumentsEpic = action$ =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType("GET_DOCUMENTS"),
        map(() => {
          const requestId = generateRequestId();
          return {
            type: "WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND",
            requestId
          };
        })
    );

const websocketMessageEpic = action$ =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType("WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND"),
        switchMap(requestId => {
          return action$.pipe(
              ofType("WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"),
              filter(action => action.requestId === requestId),
              timeout(10000),
              map(({ message }) => ({
                type: "GET_DOCUMENTS_SUCCESS",
                documents: message
              })),
              catchError(() => of({ type: "GET_DOCUMENTS_TIMEOUT" }))
          );
        })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, put me on the right track and enabled me to expand upon it for my own needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer (2020-04-17):**

I was unhappy with my original answer so decided to give it another shot.

NotificationOperators.js

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, filter, timeout, catchError, first, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { notificationActionTypes } from '../actions';

const NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000;

const generateRequestId = () => Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);

const toNotificationRequest = notificationRequest => input$ =>
    input$.pipe(mergeMap(async action => ({
        type: notificationActionTypes.WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND,
        message: {
            request_id: generateRequestId(),
            ...(
                typeof notificationRequest === "function" ?
                    await Promise.resolve(notificationRequest(action)) :
                    ({ eventType: notificationRequest })
            )
        }
    })));

const mapNotificationRequestResponses = (notificationRequest, mapper) => $input =>
    $input.pipe(
        filter(action =>
            action.type === notificationActionTypes.WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND &&
            action.message.eventType === notificationRequest),
        concatMap(sendAction =>
            $input.pipe(
                filter(receiveAction => {
                    return (
                        receiveAction.type === notificationActionTypes.WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED &&
                        receiveAction.message.request_id === sendAction.message.request_id
                    )
                }),
                first(),
                timeout(NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT),
                map(({ message }) => mapper(message.success ? false : message.error, message.result, sendAction.message)),
                catchError(errorMessage => of(mapper(errorMessage && errorMessage.message, null, sendAction.message))))));

export { toNotificationRequest, mapNotificationRequestResponses };
```

Usage:

```
export const getDocumentsReqEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(documentActionTypes.REFRESH_DOCUMENTS_REQUEST),
    toNotificationRequest(EventTypes.get_user_documents_req)
);

export const getDocumentsRecEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    mapNotificationRequestResponses(
        EventTypes.get_user_documents_req,
        (error, result) => error ? refreshDocumentsError(error) : refreshDocumentsSuccess(result))
);
```

**Original answer:**

As I felt I would likely need to repeat this process many more times, this seemed like a reasonable amount of duplicated boilterplate that I should create a method to generate epics based on requirements. For this reason I have expanded upon @sneas awesome answer and have posted below incase it helps others.

Note this implementation assumes the websocket implementation from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521444/685404). It also assumes that the server websocket implementation will accept a 'request_id' and respond with the same 'request_id' so that request and response messages can be linked. Probably also worth noting that the 'epicLinkId' is client-side only, and simply enables the 2 epics being created to be linked to each other, without this you would only be able to call `createNotifyReqResEpics()` once.

createNotifyReqResEpics.js (helper based on code above)

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, filter, timeout, catchError, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { notificationActionTypes } from '../actions';

const generateRequestId = () => Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);

export default ({
    requestFilter,
    requestMessageMapper,
    responseMessageMapper
}) => {

    if (typeof requestFilter !== "function")
        throw new Error("Invalid function passed into createNotifyReqResEpics 'requestFilter' argument.");
    if (typeof requestMessageMapper !== "function")
        throw new Error("Invalid function passed into createNotifyReqResEpics 'requestMessageMapper' argument.");
    if (typeof responseMessageMapper !== "function")
        throw new Error("Invalid function passed into createNotifyReqResEpics 'responseMessageMapper' argument.");

    const epicLinkId = generateRequestId();

    const websocketSendEpic = action$ =>
        action$.pipe(
            filter(requestFilter),
            map(action => ({
                epic_link_id: epicLinkId,
                type: notificationActionTypes.WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND,
                message: {
                    request_id: generateRequestId(),
                    ...requestMessageMapper(action)
                }
            }))
        );

    const websocketReceiveEpic = action$ =>
        action$.pipe(
            ofType(notificationActionTypes.WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SEND),
            filter(action => action.epic_link_id === epicLinkId),
            switchMap(sendAction =>
                action$.pipe(
                    ofType(notificationActionTypes.WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED),
                    filter(receiveAction => receiveAction.request_id === sendAction.request_id),
                    first(),
                    timeout(10000),
                    map(receiveAction => responseMessageMapper(false, receiveAction.message)),
                    catchError(errorMessage => of(responseMessageMapper(errorMessage && errorMessage.message, null))))));

    return [websocketSendEpic, websocketReceiveEpic];
};
```

documents.js (epics)

```
import EventTypes from '../shared-dependencies/EventTypes';
import { documentActionTypes, refreshDocumentsError, refreshDocumentsSuccess } from '../actions';
import { createNotifyReqResEpics } from '../utils';

const [getDocumentsReqEpic, getDocumentsRespEpic] = createNotifyReqResEpics({
    requestFilter: action => action.type === documentActionTypes.REFRESH_DOCUMENTS_REQUEST,
    requestMessageMapper: action => ({ eventType: EventTypes.get_user_documents_req }),
    responseMessageMapper: (error, action) => error ? refreshDocumentsError(error) : refreshDocumentsSuccess(action.result)
});

export { getDocumentsReqEpic, getDocumentsRespEpic };
```

Where the 2 exported epics from documents.js make thie way into combineEpics.